# Why does this TestNG test pass although the mock method is not invoked?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, testng, jmock

I user TestNG and jMock for my unit test but, I have a problem with TestNG. It marks the test as passed when I expect mock object method to be invoked and it is not!

```
public class SomeTestTest {


  Mockery mocker = new Mockery();

  SomeInterface someInterface = mocker.mock(SomeInterface.class);

  @Test
  public void testName() throws Exception {
    mocker.checking(new Expectations() {{
      oneOf(someInterface).someMethod();
    }});
  }
}
```

and this is the report I get

```
Custom suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a call to [`Mockery.assertIsSatisfied()`](http://www.jmock.org/javadoc/2.5.1/org/jmock/Mockery.html#assertIsSatisfied%28%29).

That call tells jMock *when* you expect all expectations to be satisfied. Otherwise it wouldn't know at which point in your code you want those to be verified.

That's also explained in the [Getting Started article](http://www.jmock.org/getting-started.html).